# Why prometheus got history data?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I have grabbed some metrics via prometheus, but it seems like I got some history data.

[image]

I used the command `curl -X GET $APISERVER/metrics --header "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" --insecure | grep apiserver_flowcontrol_dispatched_requests_total` three times in a row, result showed in the picture.

The result of the second command shows that there is no `priority_level="global-default"` data, which is indicated by red underline in the result of other two commands. The number of `priority_level="global-default"` which is indicated by yellow underline is counter data type, but the result of the second command is less than the first one.

I guess my prometheus got the history data.

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is a problem.

Yes. Prometheus is a time series database, meaning that every time you query a metric (to get a value) you get the value of that specific metric in the particular time where the query happened.

More details: https://prometheus.io/docs/introduction/overview/